# Giving light to a plant 24/7 is good?

Tags: houseplants

Can we grow plants fast and harvest more if we give light 24/7 using LEDs ?

Comment: Nope, plants as do all living things do best with rest.  They are evolved because of the day and night cycles, the moon and tides.  The plants are far more healthy with a rest cycle...stressed without and that causes susceptibility to disease and insects.

Comment: @stormy yeah but they will produce more harvest under more light , won't they ?

Comment: Most plants shut down their metabolism after 16 hours of light.  Higher production is due more to the fact that artificial light is much more consistent in its intensity then sunshine.  But more light does equal more production within these limits.  More lumens per square foot mean more production too if the plant can take the bright light and has an ample water supply.

Comment: No.  They need time to 'reset' all the processes.  If you want to maximize production you should try giving your tomatoes CO2!  Use a propane heater that is allowed to give off CO2 inside your greenhouse, grow house.  Some people actually have tried dry ice, but that is expensive.  A tank of CO2 will last a couple of weeks.  Ventilation, get that air moving to move the O2 away and allow CO2 to be present for photosynthesis.  Clean your leaves/stomata with sprays of water (careful doing this too much).  Those fans go 24/7, leaves should move in the air.  Temperature, no lower than 55 no higher

Comment: ...than 85 degrees F.  These are the things that need to be addressed for optimum growth.  Photo period differences between vegetative stage and reproductive stages is crucial!

Comment: hey stormy! could you elaborate on "Photo period differences between vegetative stage and reproductive stages is crucial!"?